# Add a Directory on a SMB Share (Files.app) to Photos.app on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, photos.app, smb, files.app

On iPad I have a Samba share (SMB) mounted with Files app.

Now how do I bring a directory from this Samba share into the Photos app? I have in a directory videos and pictures and now want to view them with Photos app (but not copy to the local iPad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photos can only access pictures stored in the Photos library. If you want to use it to look at or edit pictures stored in an SMB share, you need to use the sharing functionality within Files to add them to Photos.